# Use php variable in mysql field

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have a field in a Mysql table which contains php variable, which is used to determine the directory where a file is stored (ex. `Docs/$CompID/` and `Acc/$AccID/`).  The problem is that when I retrieve the value, the php variable name is display instead of the value.

I tried placing quotes around the value -

Both in the Mysql table (`Docs/$CompID/"` and `Docs/".$CompID."/`)

and when the php variable is displayed (`echo"$dir"`)

I also tried doing `str_replace`, putting `{ }` around the variable so that I can identify it in the string:

```
$start=strrpos($cat['dir'],'{');
$stop=strrpos($cat['dir'],'}');
$rep=substr($cat['dir'],$start+1,$stop-1);
$dir=str_replace("{".$rep."}",$rep,$cat['dir']);
```

All of these just displayed the php variable name.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what does `$cat['dir']` look like ?

Comment: Docs/$CompID/ and Acc/$AccID/ are examples of the type of data in $cat['dir'].  When I was trying to use str_replace I changed them to Docs/{$CompID}/ and Acc/{$AccID}/...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

```
$AccID = 'me';
eval("\$str = \"Acc/$AccID/\";");
echo $str;
```

Comment: This works if I save the variable into another one like this:

$dir=$cat['dir'];
eval("\$str = \"$dir\";");
echo $str;

But not like this:

eval("\$str = \"$cat['dir']\";");
echo $str;


Any idea why?

Comment: Oh yah forgot my PHP quotes stuff. That's funny

Comment: Acc/$AccID/ is the value of $cat['dir'].  Works like eval("\$str = \"$cat[dir]\";");  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct you variable would look like this: `var`. You can access `$var` with `$$cat["dir"]`. However, if you db variable looks like `$var`, just use a simple substring to remove the `$`.

Comment: I tried this, but it only worked if the php variable was the only thing in the Mysql field. When there is text along with the variable in the field, it to use the entire value as a variable.

Comment: This is really great to know, though!! I will definitely keep this in mind, though, when the entire Mysql field is a php variable!